# INSERT data from Textbox to Postgres SQL

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, npgsql

I just learn how to connect C# and PostgresSQL.
I want to INSERT data from tb1(Textbox) and tb2 to database. But I don't know how to code
My previous code is SELECT from database.
this is my code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool blnfound = false;
        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=admin123;Database=Login");
        conn.Open();
        NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM login WHERE name='" + tb1.Text + "' and password = '" + tb2.Text + "'",conn);
        NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read())
        {
            blnfound = true;
            Form2 f5 = new Form2();
            f5.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        if (blnfound == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Name or password is incorrect", "Message Box", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
            dr.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

So please help me the code.

Answer (score 12):

First off, you need to use the `ExecuteNonQuery` method rather than `ExecuteReader` since you're executing an `INSERT` rather than a `SELECT` statement.  So, something like:

```
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("insert into table1 values(1, 1)", conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The `ExecuteNonQuery` method will also return the number of rows affected if that's important for you.

Second, you need to use SQL parameters rather than building an unsafe SQL string.

Use:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("name", tb1.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("pw", tb2.Text));
```

To add a parameter to your query.  You can now refer to it in your INSERT statement with `:name` or `:pw`, for example:

```
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("insert into login (Name, Password) values(:name, :pw)", conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Lastly, you might be interested in using an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) rather than executing raw SQL statements.  I'd check into the [.NET Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) or [Castle Active Record](http://www.castleproject.org/), which is built on [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx).  These libraries will allow you to query, update, create and delete data within your database without writing the actual SQL statements involved.  It's a great way to get started, and will simply your code quite a bit!

Comment: You may also want to have a look at Npgsql manual which has a lot of working examples: http://manual.npgsql.org I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for mentioning Castle Active Record, Haven't heard of it before,