# Trying to update column on C# using Npgsql

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I'm trying to update the value of a column using Npgsql (PostgreSQL) and Visual Studio 2015. This is a "Forgot your Password?" form.

The user needs to enter two variables in order to accomplish the reset (an if condition):
1. enter the SSN (aka RG in Brazil); and
2. enter a user-specific code that is unchangeable.

What happens is: when I try to change the value (using the command below), nothing happens.

```
NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("UPDATE dbschema.dbtable SET senha = '" + textBox2.Text + "' WHERE rg = '" + textBox2.Text + "'");
```

The if condition executes perfectly (I tied the if command to a Message box, where it shows that the password has been successfully reseted - a sign that the if condition was indeed executed) - the only thing that doesn't happen right now is the password update (which might be a minor feature in the release, as I'd prefer to reset myself on the database). I tried several changes in the code, with no success yet.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Lucas

Comment: It's not very clear what you're actually asking.  If you're saying that your query doesn't update the DB, then check your input, or try hard coding the value you match against.  It's best to use a parameterised query as well; your existing command is vulnerable to SQL injection.  As a final comment, you're using `textbox2.Text` in both values in the SQL command - that doesn't seem right.

Comment: I'm trying to update a value on the "password" column by verifying the unique user code and the SSN. However, the value is not being updated when I click the "update password" button.

Comment: It seems like you're storing passwords as plain text in a database, which is quite a big red flag security-wise.

Comment: Right. I'm looking into it, didn't think about it before. Tnks. (it's an academic project btw)

Answer (score 1):

You have to actually open a database connection and execute the command, e.g.:

```
using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(<connection string>)) {
    var command = new NpgsqlCommand("UPDATE dbschema.dbtable SET senha = '" + textBox2.Text + "' WHERE rg = '" + textBox2.Text + "'", conn);
    conn.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Note that the way you pass parameters is also open to SQL injection attacks. You should look at parameterized queries.

Comment: Yeah, I've opened. Just omitted because thought it wasn't important on the context...

Comment: BTW: NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=5432; User Id=admin;Password=databasepw; Database=dbdb;");
            con.Open();

Comment: Yes, the result is the same. On the login page, it complains about the password again.

Comment: (looks like I didn't read your comment about the SQL injection attacks. Will look forward into this, tnks.)

Answer (score 0):

Had you tried to execute `NpgsqlCommand`?

Also, You better use parametrized queries.

See this example: [INSERT data from Textbox to Postgres SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237431/insert-data-from-textbox-to-postgres-sql)

Comment: I've used a code similar to the one I've used on the login. As it sends the data to the PostgreSQL successfully (and absorbs the data on the text boxes correctly in this case)...but I'll try your suggestion now. Tks!