# Desktop admin panel for web app

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, laravel-5, web-applications

I'm building a eCommerce web application for shops using Laravel/Foundation/PostgreSQL, and it will provide them (shop owners) with web based admin panel. My question is, can I make the super admin panel (the tool that I use to control everything) using desktop technology such as VB.net (or anything similar) so the desktop app control the database and maybe some configuration files. Is this considered good way to do things, and do anyone have a similar experience here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,it's possible to create such application.This kindda application can be called somewhat 'Database Applications'...Let me explain :

1 • You can develop such app in either C#/Vb.NET

2 • Basically, what you need is an app which will let you modify the database(e.g. Product name/Price/Quantity)

3 • For this, you need to first set up a connection between your app and your PostGre database.Take a look at [this)

4 • Then you can use textboxes,checkboxes,Listboxes and other controls you want to edit/delete/update the database . For this, take a look at [this for inserting data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237431/insert-data-from-textbox-to-postgres-sql) and [this for updating data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24287396/update-command-using-npgsql-postgres-and-c-sharp) .They are in c# but can easily be converted to vb.net using converter.telerik.com or simillar conversion tools

I guess that's all you need for now.Leave a comment for further assistance .